# Redirecting subdomain to another domain

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, 301-redirect

I have a subdomain, sub.domain1.com. I want to redirect this to domain2.com.

The result is a security exception because the certificate on domain2.com doesn't include sub.domain1.com.

How does one deal with this redirect issue without adding sub.domain1.com to domain2.com's certificate?

Comment: _If_ you mean HTTPS i.e. the web -- which you didn't actually say and is not the only protocol that uses SSL/TLS -- and unless you or your users have truly ancient browsers or defective clients, many (but not all) webservers support using two (or more) certs selected by [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Details vary greatly depending on the server which you didn't specify.

Answer (score 0):

You need a webserver answering on `sub.domain1.com` that sends a 301 redirect with the new location set to `https:/domain2.com`.